# Problems mapping a series to a min(list, key=lambda x: abs(series)) function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I want to find a number in `series`, and find which number it's closest to in `[1,2,3]`. Then use the `key` to replace the series value with the appropriate letter.

```
key = {1: 'A', 2:'B', 3:'C')
series = pd.Series([x*1.2 for x in range(10)])


pd.DataFrame = key[min([1,2,3], key=lambda x: abs(x-series))]
```

The `series` is a column from the `pd.DataFrame`, I've just tried to simplify it for here.

Comment: Could you add a sample case of `series` and expected output? Also, the title says : `Problems`, so what kinda problems did you have?

Answer (score 1):

use the `apply` method and then `map` your `Series` such has:

```
key = {1: 'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}
series = pd.Series([x*1.2 for x in range(10)])

def find(myNumber):
    return min([1,2,3], key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber))

series.apply(find).map(key)
Out[50]: 
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    C
5    C
6    C
7    C
8    C
9    C
dtype: object
```

it also should work if you replace series by the entire dataframe such has:

```
df.apply(find).map(key)
```